# How can someone prevent others from taking/using their magic item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Seems simple: you have a powerful item that you don't want the BBEG to steal and destroy or use against you. Are there any effects you can apply to it via crafting that will help keep it in your possession or let you instantly take it back?

And if not, can you at least craft effects that cause harmful side-effects to wielders other than yourself (like how the *life-drinker* gives negative levels to wielders who aren't undead/constructs) or make it weaker when others use it (like how the *holy avenger* has a lower enchantment bonus and fewer special abilities when used by non-paladins)?

Comment: What's the powerful item?

Comment: Could be a sword, armor, ring... In general I like to have this kind of thing, so if there are different methods for different items, then that's all good!

Answer (score 14):

First, unless the campaign makes magic items objects unusually rare, nobody's actually going out of their way to steal magic items. Sure, if the magic item's an original magic item or an artifact, it'll be a target, but that's a story. In a typical campaign, most magic items can just be purchased with money in a big enough town by anyone who wants one. Rather than stealing from an adventurer—who is, to be clear, frequently a casual killer who holds a  grudge forever—, it's usually easier and safer to steal money and use that money buy a magic item.

Second, money that's spent keeping an existing magic item safe—essentially, buying insurance—is money that could've been spent on more or better magic items. Normally, an adventurer buys and sells more and better magic items at a pretty good clip, but a paranoid adventurer who invests heavily in insurance is in stasis. Her magic items *are* safer, but her personal power remains largely unchanged while other adventurers see their power steadily increase by participating in the traditional adventurer economy.

In short, an adventurer's job is to defeat enemies then take their valuables. Money spent on more and better magic items facilitates defeating enemies; insurance doesn't facilitate defeating enemies. Unless the adventurer's shtick is getting captured, invoking her coverage to regain her equipment, then defeating her enemies from within—making James Bond very proud—, my experience has been that it's generally better to spend literally nothing or, at most, the absolute minimum on insurance.

Still, the DM may be running an atypical campaign that's stocked with lucky, foolhardy thieves. Or the DM enjoys making players lives miserable by stealing the PCs' stuff. Or the DM accidentally let fall into the PCs' hands a magic item that's too powerful for their levels and, rather than talking to the players and admitting the mistake, feels like he must deal with his mistake during play. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67284/8610).) Or the campaign or the players may have something else going on or whatever. With this mind, the remainder of this answer attempts offers the paranoid adventurer peace of mind.

For convenience, this answer's remainder assumes the adventurer wants to protect from theft and destruction, retrieve instantaneously, and modify so that they're less powerful in another's possession an [*amulet of the planes*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#amulet-of-the-planes) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 247) (120,000 gp; 0 lbs.) and a [*staff of power*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsSSW.html#staff-of-power) (245) (211,000 gp; 4 lbs.). Both are otherwise normal magic items.

---

## Deterring an object's theft

Here's how to make magic items less appetizing targets for thieves on the cheap.

- **Stay vigilant.** A [*ring of sustenance*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-sustenance) (*DMG* 233) (2,500 gp; 0 lbs.), in addition to other effects, means a typical creature needs only 2 hours of sleep. Instead of sleeping, a typical elf need only trance for 4 hours and, while doing so, remains aware of her surroundings. And a warforged just doesn't sleep. Thieves are slightly more reluctant to steal from professional killers that are also conscious and mobile.
- **Make the magic item appear dangerous.** In a typical setting the vast majority know nothing about magic. (The skill [Knowledge](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#knowledge) (arcana) doesn't yield a lot of information when used untrained, and the skill [Spellcraft](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#spellcraft) typically can't be used untrained at all.) However, only barbarians and totemists are actually illiterate, so if a staff or amulet has an engraving that says *Unauthorized possession of this item will kill the possessor*, it may give thieves pause. Of course, if *every* adventurer engraves *all* her stuff with such notes and it's *never* true, this isn't a deterrent, but if this kind of thing is unfashionable or if every tenth time it *is* true then theft becomes less likely.
- **Keep the magic item safe when not in use.** A thief that wants a staff or amulet must somehow swipe the glove from the wearer's hand if, when the magic item's not in use, the wearer keeps the amulet or staff in a *glove of the master strategist* (*Ghostwalk* 71) (3,600 gp; 0 lbs.). (It's a better and less expensive [*glove of  storing*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#glove-of-storing) (*DMG* 257) (10,000 gp; 0 lbs.).) Similarly, the magic item is *on another plane* if it's kept in a *Heward's handy haversack* (259) (2,000 gp; 5 lbs.) *et al.* (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37842/8610).) Containers are often easier to protect than the items themselves (e.g. with a *glyph seal* (*Magic Item Compendium* 161) (1,000+ gp; 0 lbs.) or ten; also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119117/8610).)
- **Make the magic item appear nonmagical.** The 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*Nystul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Nystul)'s [magic aura](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#magic-aura) [illus] (*Player's Handbook* 257–8) can, among other effects, cause a magic item to appear nonmagical. A fancy amulet or a masterwork staff may still appear valuable (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122017/8610)), but if the item does not also register as magical, then it'll probably be a less desirable target for thieves.  Although the *magic aura* spell is usually a temporary measure with a duration of 1 day/level, the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*permanency*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#permanency) [univ] (259–60) says that the "DM may allow other selected spells to be made permanent" if a caster successfully researches an original spell (*DMG* 198) of the desired spell level—in this case, 1st-level. If the researcher takes 1 week, spends 1,000 gp, and succeeds on a Spellcraft skill check (DC 11)—and if the DM rules that it's viable to add the *magic aura* spell to the *permanency* spell list—, that researcher can thereafter use a *permanency* spell on the *magic aura* spell so that a magic item permanently appears nonmagical when magic is detected for. (This permanent *magic aura* spell will also probably cost a caster at least 500 XP.)

## Deterring an object's destruction

Money spent on making a magic item more difficult to destroy is usually money spent poorly. While it's a good idea for anyone who wears magical metal armor to buy for that armor the magic armor special ability ***durable*** (*Dungeonscape* 39) (500 gp; 0 lbs.), typically only creatures that possess an Intelligence score of 2 or less will outright destroy an adventurer's gear—and, even then, usually that's a side effect of their normal attacks—, but the occasional [honey badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_badger#In_popular_culture)-like intelligent foe may specialize in such a tactic.

- **Magically toughen magic items.** While the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell *hardening* [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 109–10) doesn't change an item's break DC, but it does increase an object's hardness by +1 per 2 caster levels, and its duration is permanent (but not, sadly, instantaneous, so multiple castings won't stack). A typical level 11 wizard charges 710 gp for one casting of the *hardening* spell.
- **Get magic items made of riverine.** An item made from the special material riverine (*Stormwrack* 128) is even more indestructible than a [*wall of force*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wall-of-force) effect—so, like, *very* indestructible—, yet creating an item from it adds 2,000 gp per pound of the item to the item's price. However, an *amulet of the planes*—and many other items, both magical and mundane—possess negligible weight, making it so that it's free to create such items from riverine. I suspect that the typical DM will quickly put a damper on this, but a more generous DM may reach this conclusion naturally. Really, if a creature wants a largely indestructible magic item, this is the way.

Also, a few broken magic items—like wondrous items (like an *amulet of the planes*) and weapons (perhaps, with a generous DM, like a *staff of power*)—can be restored to functionality by those that're also capable of creating the magic item for half the cost, time, and XP that it takes to make a new one normally.

## Recovering a stolen object

This reader suspects this is so incredibly difficult because doing so is supposed to be an adventure.

- **Maybe a weapon augment crystal?** A masterwork weapon—and that includes a magic staff, as a magic staff must be made from a masterwork quarterstaff (as per *DMG* 284)—can accept a least weapon augment crystal, and a weapon with a +1 magical enhancement bonus can accept a lesser crystal. The *crystal of return (lesser)* (*MIC* 65) (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.) allows the owner to take a move action to cause the weapon to return to his hand… if the weapon's unattended and within 30 ft.
- **Maybe an *instant summons* spell?** The 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell *[Drawmij](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Ward_(game_designer))'s [instant summons](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#instant-summons)* [conj] (*PH* 225) allows a caster to crush a prepared 1,000-gp sapphire to bring from anywhere into the crusher's hand a prepared unattended object. (A noncaster probably must use the skill Use Magic Device to cast the needed spells.) If the object is attended, the crusher knows who attends the object and "roughly where that creature is located" when he crushed the gem. Excluding the sapphire, a level 13 caster charges 975 gp total for this effect, but only the *instant summons* spell's caster can cause the effect occur. (Others can still crush the sapphire, although that's kind of mean, and nothing'll happen.)
- **An intelligent magic item may facilitate its own return.** For an additional 4,000 gp, an intelligent magic becomes capable of speech (*DMG* 269); it can just annoy its thief until it's returned or silenced. Alternatively—and subject to minor adjustments by the DM in light of the *3.5* revision—an intelligent magic item can once per day employ the extraordinary power [*teleport*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#teleport) as if its caster level were 12 (*Arms & Equipment Guide* 139) (21,600 gp; 0 lbs.). Such an intelligent magic item can use that extraordinary power to go wherever it wants—while adhering to that effect's limits, of course. (The bearer's permission isn't required.)

## Modifying a magic item so that while it's in another's possession it causes discomfort, it's nonfunctional, or it functions at reduced efficacy

This [fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162046/8610) mentions these options also, but let me offer a different take.

- **An intelligent magic item bestows negative levels on a misaligned bearer.** Nobody likes [negative levels](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#energy-drain-and-negative-levels), and an intelligent magic item—even a very basic one (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.) (*DMG* 269)—bestows upon a possessor with an incompatible alignment 1 negative level… and an intelligent magic item with an ego score of 20 to 29 bestows 2, and one with an ego score of at least 30 bestows 3. Further, an intelligent item that possesses an alignment of CG, CE, LE, LG, or N is incompatible with *any* creature that possesses an alignment not matching its own *exactly*. (This reader thinks LG safest: Really, circumstances would have to be pretty weird for, like, a LG [solar](http://dndsrd.net/monstersA.html#solar-angel) to swipe a LG PC's intelligent LG *amulet of the planes*! Enjoy playing *that* story!)
- **Guarantee the loyalty of an intelligent magic item.** First, the caster finds or makes a creature whose disposition toward the caster is at least [helpful](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#diplomacy) if not [fanatic](http://dndsrd.net/epicSkills.html#diplomacy). Then on that creature the caster casts the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell *Nybor's psychic imprint* [trans] (Magic Books of Faerûn column ["*Nybor's Small Codex*: Spells from a Former Zulkir"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20041215a)) that copies the creature's personality into a (really, really expensive) gem. The caster then duct tapes that gem to a magic item to transfer the personality copy into the magic item. Forevermore thereafter, the magic item's attitude toward the caster remains unchanged. While the magic item largely can't *stop* a thief from using its abilities, it will likely use its powers, try to dominate the thief, and just chat up the thief all in an effort to hasten its return to its ally. (A caster might also want to have on hand for the original creature a [*greater restoration*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#greater-restoration) effect… or not. I mean, c'mon, those are expensive!) (The *DMG* is vague on [Intelligent Item Creation](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#intelligent-item-creation) (288), but this method ensures the caster creates one that possesses a personality he desires.)
- **A new magic item can be created so that its power is reduced if it's in the wrong creature's possession.** If the DM is using the Variant: New Magic Items (*DMG* 214), a new magic item's description can include that it functions differently or not at all while in the possession of a creature that doesn't meet certain requirements. The *DMG* on Behind the Curtain: Magic Item Gold Piece Values specifically mentions magic items that require a certain class or alignment to use (282), but, as a new magic item's description is concocted by the player, the player can develop whatever restrictions she likes. However, creating new magic items remains at the discretion of the DM, and the DM can veto new magic items he doesn't like. Further, adding requirements to an existing magic item is also at the DM's discretion. (This last goes unmentioned by the *DMG*.)

Comment: You have many excellent answers here, but somehow I had missed this one until now, and I must say, even by your lofty standards, this is phenomenal.

Comment: Marvellous answer! Minor nitpick, though: Items stored in a Heward's Handy haversack or Bag of Holding aren't on another plane, they're in a "nondimensional space," i.e.: a space that's larger on the inside than the outside. There's nothing in 3.5rd edition's rules that suggests a nondimensional space is extraplanar, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @GMJoe See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37842/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Huh, that was an interesting read. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Here are some:

- Custom Magic Items.  The custom magic item rules in the DMG suggests that a DM should give a player price *reductions* when crafting an item with additional restrictions on usage.  That seems silly, but it is what the text says.  In particular, you should get a 10% reduction in price if your item requires a skill to use, and a 30% reduction in price if it requires a particular race, class, and/or alignment.  Since the rules for this are in the DMG and are phrased as part of the DM's process for estimating the gp value of custom magic items, this method may well be forbidden to players in any particular game.
- Sentient Magic Items.  The Sentient Magic Item rules let you create a being with a Special Purpose and phenomenal cosmic power that is leveraged in the furtherance of that purpose.  One possible purpose for items is "Defend the servants and interests of a specific deity" which could be you, provided you are a deity.  Even without claiming the mantle of godhood, an intelligent item can be excellent protection against theft or misuse.  A wielder whose alignment is not in accord with the item can suffer up to 3 save-less unremovable negative levels, as well as forcing a Will save to avoid being forced to, e.g., immediately surrender.
- The -2 Cursed Sword allows a wielder who bears it for at least a week to draw it automatically whenever they wish to draw any weapon (we usually run this as the sword teleporting into the wielder's hands).  As long as you draw it at least once a week, then, no one else will be able to establish such a bond with the weapon and you needn't worry about losing it to theft. You can upgrade the sword, just like any other item, with the Craft Magic Arms and Armor feat.
- The locked gauntlet keeps you from dropping or being disarmed of a weapon.  It's also a mundane piece of equipment, so there's no real reason not to have one or several.
- Traps can keep people from messing with your stuff.  Especially magic traps.  For example, *glyph of warding* or *explosive runes* or *symbol of pain*.

The first two of these countermeasures are easily defeated via UMD and protect against usage but not theft.  The last one requires a casting of *limited wish* before theft can be practically attempted, and that spell allows Spell Resistance.  I have used the -2 cursed sword before to safe-keep expensive custom magic powers and have found it very useful, particularly if it can be used in conjuncture with sentience and a race/alignment/skill restriction.

Comment: Where do I find the rules on creating Sentient Magic Items?

Comment: @Giorin Start [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84296/8610)

Comment: And intelligent items are able to use all of the powers of the items themselves. Consider adding one casting of a Summon Monster spell to an intelligent item.  Even if the item can't move on its own, if it summons a creature under its control that's just as good. Alternatively giving an item the ability to cast Minor Image would allow it to maintain concentration on the illusion for however long it wishes. Rather than just talking to the thief, making them constantly see ghosts out of the corner of their eye and then having them disappear when other people show up would be pretty fun.

Answer (score 1):

Several cheap options exist for detecting intruders or when certain conditions have been met, notably including the Alarm, Magic Mouth, and Glyph of Warding spells. Marking whichever space you left your items in will allow you some peace of mind. Also the Glyph Seal item provides a handy, reusable way to create Glyphs of Warding.

More expensive and cumbersome options for trapping your possessions include the Explosive Runes and Sepia Snake Sigil spells. Both of these require tricking and he would be thieves into reading a message they understand, but having something immediately blow up in their face or lock them in stasis for 1d4 + caster level days can both come in handy. (It is very important to note, however, that explosive runes explicitly destroy the surface they are written on.) If greater firepower is necessary then the Explosive Spike or Blast Disc items can be used instead. Unfortunately, these do not have the same flexibility as other options, so bypassing them is not as simple as teaching your allies a passphrase.

In the event that you are seeking to recover an item that is already stolen, another option that is excellent is the second level spell Dragoneye Rune. It has a permanent effect that allows you to scry the marked subject more easily, and allows you to sense the direction and distance between you and the item multiple times a day for free.

And at the upper end of expensive options is the well-known Contingency spell, which has a reputation for allowing abuse, and will probably require calmly negotiating it's exact limits with your DM. On the upside, it is extremely flexible and could probably handle just about any task you need to protect your property.